# Cannot Convert string to 'char*' for argument error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char, boolean

I do not understand what this error is saying in my C++ code

> error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to
>   'char' for argument '1' to 'bool areParenthesesBalanced(char*)'
>
> if(areParenthesesBalanced(str))

My Code:

```
bool areParenthesesBalanced(char expr[])
{
    stack<char> s;
    char a, b, c;

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(expr); i++)
    {
        if (expr[i]=='(' || expr[i]=='[' || expr[i]=='{')
        {
            s.push (expr[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (expr[i])
            {
                case ')':
                a = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (a=='{' || a=='[')
                cout<<"Not Balanced";
                break;

                case '}':
                b = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (b=='(' || b=='[')
                cout<<"Not Balanced";
                break;

                case ']':
                c = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (c=='(' || c=='{')
                cout<<"Not Balanced";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (s.empty())  //check if stack is empty
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream t("file.txt");
    std::string str;
    t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    str.reserve(t.tellg());
    t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    if(areParenthesesBalanced(str))
    {
        cout<<"Balanced";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not Balanced";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand what it is seeing as the issue! Any ideas?

Comment: Why is expr a char array and not a std::string? Why do you call your function with std::string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `std::string::c_str()`

Read Here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

But as the name suggests, this makes your code look more like C than C++. It is better to pass a const reference of `std::string` and use foreach syntax (ranged-based for loop) or `std::string::size()`.

Revised code (C++11):

```
bool areParenthesesBalanced(const std::string &expr)
{
    const std::unordered_map<char, char> parens { {')', '('}, {']', '['}, {'}', '{'} };
    std::stack<char> paren_stack;

    for (const auto chr : expr)
    {
        switch (chr)
        {
        case '(':
        case '[':
        case '{':
            paren_stack.push(chr);
            break;

        case ')':
        case ']':
        case '}':
        {
            const auto val = paren_stack.top();
            paren_stack.pop();
            if (parens.find(chr)->second != val) {
                std::cout << "Not Balanced";
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return paren_stack.empty();
}
```

Comment: And OP also must change `char expr[]` to `const char expr[]`. (Or even better `const std::string &expr`.)

Comment: Where should I fix this at?

Comment: If it works for you vote up and accept.  Also notice you need to include `string`, `stack`, `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your function declaration to:

```
bool areParenthesesBalanced(const std::string& expr)
```

There is no need to convert to `char []`.  You can use the `[]` operator with strings.

Comment: I tried this and I get "error: cannot convert 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)'  for(int i = 0; i<strlen(expr); i++)

Comment: std::string has a member function length.

Comment: OP would need to `#include <string>` as well.